# SelectField Not Returning Boolean Value for DB

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I'm going a bit crazy here. I can not not figure out how to get a Boolean value transferred to my DB using SQLAlchemy. I've tried both BooleanField and SelectField. It keeps returning a null value Please help.

What it shows in my DB is either a 1 or 0 to represent True and False. I then take those values from the DB and display them on my webpage

Python

```
with app.app_context():
    class Cafe(db.Model):
        id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        name = db.Column(db.String(250), unique=True, nullable=False)
        map_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
        img_url = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
        location = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
        seats = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=False)
        has_toilet = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
        has_wifi = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
        has_sockets = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
        can_take_calls = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
        coffee_price = db.Column(db.String(250), nullable=True)

        db.session.commit()


class NewCafe(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField("Cafe Name", validators=[DataRequired()])
    map_url = StringField("Map URL", validators=[DataRequired(), URL()])
    img_url = StringField("Image URL", validators=[DataRequired(), URL()])
    location = StringField("Address", validators=[DataRequired()])
    coffee_price = StringField("Average Price", validators=[DataRequired()])
    seats = StringField("Seats?", validators=[DataRequired()])
    has_toilet = SelectField("Toilet? ", choices=[('', 'No'), (True, 'Yes')], coerce=bool)
    has_wifi = SelectField("WiFi? ", choices=[('', 'No'), (True, 'Yes')], coerce=bool)
    has_sockets = SelectField("Sockets? ", choices=[('', 'No'), (True, 'Yes')], coerce=bool)
    can_take_calls = SelectField("Take Calls? ", choices=[('', 'No'), (True, 'Yes')], coerce=bool)
    submit = SubmitField("Submit Post")

@app.route("/new-post", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def new_post():
    form = NewCafe(active=True)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_post = Cafe(
            name=request.form.get('name'),
            map_url=request.form.get('map_url'),
            location=request.form.get('location'),
            img_url=request.form.get('img_url'),
            has_sockets=bool(request.form.get("sockets")),
            has_toilet=bool(request.form.get("toilet")),
            has_wifi=bool(request.form.get("wifi")),
            can_take_calls=bool(request.form.get("calls")),
            coffee_price=request.form.get("coffee_price"),
            seats=request.form.get("seats"),
        )

        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('get_all_posts'))
    return render_template("make-post.html", form=form)
```

HTML: This is where I'm calling the form

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">

          {{ ckeditor.load() }}

          {{ ckeditor.config(name='body') }}

          {{ wtf.quick_form(form, novalidate=True, button_map={"submit": "primary"}) }}

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use these libs so I'm not sure which versions you are using but I think you need to:

- call `form.validate_on_submit()`.
- then retrieve data from `form.has_toilet.data`, in the pattern `<form variable>.<field attribute>.data`

I think the problem was you were getting raw unvalidated field data from `request.form`.  Also seems that some of your field names didn't match the form definition.  Here is the updated code I used:

```py
@app.route("/new-post", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def new_post():
    form = NewCafe()

    if form.validate_on_submit():
        new_post = Cafe(
            name=form.name.data,
            map_url=form.map_url.data,
            location=form.location.data,
            img_url=form.img_url.data,
            has_sockets=form.has_sockets.data,
            has_toilet=form.has_toilet.data,
            has_wifi=form.has_wifi.data,
            can_take_calls=form.can_take_calls.data,
            coffee_price=form.coffee_price.data,
            seats=form.seats.data,
        )
        db.session.add(new_post)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('get_all_posts'))
    return render_template("make-post.html", form=form)
```

I tested this with:

- flask_wtf 1.0.1
- flask 2.2.2
- sqlalchemy 1.4.46
- Flask-Bootstrap 3.3.7.1
- WTForms 3.0.1
- flask-sqlalchemy 3.0.2

Comment: Of course. How could I be so stupid? I had written that pattern because I was trying everything. The way you have it now is the way I wrote it originally. What I forgot was 'if form.validate_on_submit():'. A million thanks to you, my friend.